# Know when BigQuery job is done without getting results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using the Node.js SDK for BigQuery.

I am creating a query job to insert the results of a query into a table. I want to know when it is complete. The way to do this that I see in the documentation is to await `job.getQueryResults()`. However, I don't want to bring the results into memory since there could be a lot and I don't need them. I did see that the method takes an object which can have the property `maxResults` which I could set to 0 but that seems kind of janky.

The best I could come up with from the documentation is to do the following:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  job.on('complete', (metadata) => {
    resolve(metadata);
  });
  job.on('error', (err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
});
```

Is there a better/preferred way to do this where I don't have to construct my own promise? This just seems like a common scenario and I figured there would be a more convenient/intuitive way to do this.

Comment: I'm of a mind that saying you want to run a query and want `maxResults` returned to be zero feels right.  I asked myself how I would do it with raw REST and came away thinking this API request ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults  and again with maxResults = 0

Comment: I might do that. Just seemed odd to use a method for getting results and not getting any :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting @Kolban's comment as answer:

I'm of a mind that saying you want to run a query and want `maxResults` returned to be zero feels right.

I asked myself how I would do it with raw REST and came away thinking this API request ... [getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) and again with `maxResults = 0`

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.